# Block all CONNECT requests to all ports

Tags: apache-http-server, connection, webserver

i have a nextcloud installation and some other webapps ive built on my home server. Strangely lately im getting attacks (not succesful ones) and its slowing down my network.

I would like to know if there is a way i can block all CONNECT requests. I use apache.

im attaching a log for you to see what im dealing with.

Some IPs have been blocked by iptables using `iptables -I INPUT -s <IP> -j DROP`

```
37.27.32.251 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:20 +0200] "CONNECT kosher.sex:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 546 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.32.251 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:20 +0200] "CONNECT kosher.sex:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 546 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.32.251 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:20 +0200] "CONNECT kosher.sex:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 546 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
95.217.153.116 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:20 +0200] "CONNECT cloud.bowlan.xyz:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 552 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.32.251 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:20 +0200] "CONNECT kosher.sex:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 546 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.7.220 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:21 +0200] "CONNECT furia.gg:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 544 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.32.251 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:21 +0200] "CONNECT kosher.sex:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 546 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.32.251 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:21 +0200] "CONNECT kosher.sex:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 546 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.32.251 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:21 +0200] "CONNECT kosher.sex:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 546 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.32.251 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:21 +0200] "CONNECT kosher.sex:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 546 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.32.251 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:21 +0200] "CONNECT kosher.sex:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 546 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.7.220 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:21 +0200] "CONNECT furia.gg:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 544 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.32.251 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:21 +0200] "CONNECT kosher.sex:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 546 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
65.109.136.10 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:21 +0200] "CONNECT furia.gg:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 544 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.32.251 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:21 +0200] "CONNECT kosher.sex:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 546 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.32.251 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:22 +0200] "CONNECT kosher.sex:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 546 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
65.109.136.10 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:22 +0200] "CONNECT furia.gg:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 544 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.32.251 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:22 +0200] "CONNECT kosher.sex:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 546 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
95.217.209.146 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:22 +0200] "CONNECT www.consus.co.kr:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 552 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
95.217.209.146 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:22 +0200] "CONNECT www.consus.co.kr:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 552 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.7.220 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:22 +0200] "CONNECT furia.gg:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 544 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.32.251 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:22 +0200] "CONNECT kosher.sex:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 546 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
95.217.209.146 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:23 +0200] "CONNECT www.consus.co.kr:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 552 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.7.220 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:23 +0200] "CONNECT furia.gg:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 544 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
95.217.209.146 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:23 +0200] "CONNECT www.consus.co.kr:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 552 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.24.250 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:23 +0200] "CONNECT com-lnsubdpkclwkdwgdsqs8k6knzkdabqh9lyo8ogbatgov8xtzayindex.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 599 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.7.220 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:23 +0200] "CONNECT furia.gg:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 544 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
95.217.153.116 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:23 +0200] "CONNECT cloud.bowlan.xyz:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 552 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.24.250 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:24 +0200] "CONNECT com-lnsubdpkclwkdwgdsqs8k6knzkdabqh9lyo8ogbatgov8xtzayindex.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 599 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
65.109.136.10 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:24 +0200] "CONNECT furia.gg:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 544 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.24.250 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:24 +0200] "CONNECT com-lnsubdpkclwkdwgdsqs8k6knzkdabqh9lyo8ogbatgov8xtzayindex.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 599 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.32.251 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:25 +0200] "CONNECT kosher.sex:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 546 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.32.251 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:25 +0200] "CONNECT kosher.sex:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 546 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
95.217.209.146 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:25 +0200] "CONNECT www.consus.co.kr:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 552 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.7.220 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:25 +0200] "CONNECT furia.gg:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 544 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
65.109.136.10 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:25 +0200] "CONNECT furia.gg:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 544 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
65.109.136.10 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:25 +0200] "CONNECT furia.gg:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 544 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
65.109.136.10 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:25 +0200] "CONNECT furia.gg:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 544 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.24.250 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:23:25 +0200] "CONNECT com-lnsubdpkclwkdwgdsqs8k6knzkdabqh9lyo8ogbatgov8xtzayindex.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 502 599 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.27.24.250 - - [18/Mar/2024:18:20:52 +0200] "CONNECT com-lnsubdpkclwkdwgdsqs8k6knzkdabqh9lyo8ogbatgov8xtzayindex.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 503 473 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: They're coming from the same IP. look into a system you can setup that auto-ban's ip addresses after x failed connection attempts. Banning usually goes using the firewall.

Comment: CONNECT is an HTTP verb. Looks like Apache isn't allowing it, which is unsurprising. It won't work unless you explicitly set up Apache as a forward proxy. Why do anything?

Comment: @LPChip im sorry for the stupid question, but how could i do that? or more importantly where can i learn about that? Im using iptables and i have firewallD (im using webmin for my "web interface")
also thank you for your response

Comment: @DanielB i had that specific "domain" as a proxy for another url (subdomain.domain.com -> domain.com:port)

Comment: The same ip adress shows up a lot in your list. You could, for now, manually ban that ip in your firewall and evaluate if its enough. If not, you'll have to figure out what the options are for you, given that I don't know what comes bundled with your vps.

Comment: @LPChip its actually a server that i have built myself, located in my house. I have webmin installed just for virtual server handling etc and having a web interface to manage the server. I have manually blocked about 20-30 IPs (ip tables converts it into names if im correct) and just now enabled the DDos protection in cloudflare since i use it for DNS and caching. is there a rule i can make to block an IP just like you said above? Thanks again

Comment: look into the OS you're using if there's an app available. There must be. For example, for Windows, you could use RDPDefender, which, surprisingly despite its name, will even block too many wrong LAN authentications attempts for network shares.

Comment: @LPChip sorry i forgot to mention im using linux (Ubuntu Linux 22.04.4 Server). Do you have any recommendations for that?

Comment: No, I have little experience with Ubuntu. But I'm sure your google skills will not fail you.

Comment: You could use [fail2ban](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban), which will do it automatically for you.

Comment: @LPChip ok, i will look it up, thank you a lot

Comment: @harrymc i have fail2ban but i have not configured it for apache, just for webmin auth banning, i will try setting it up thank you lots. Do you have any tutorials that you would recommend?

Comment: Example link [here](https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/how-to-install-fail2ban-to-protect-apache-server/). Or download from the github project release.